# error to print pdf in linux with Snappy PDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, snappy

i have a problem with the configuration file in config/snappy.php
programming in windows i have this configuration, work really good, the problem is when i put the code in my production app in linux, the configuration is not the same....

```
return array(
    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
       'binary' => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"',       
       //'binary' => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf"',
        'options' => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => '"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe"',
        'options' => array(),
    ),
);
```

I try with this configuration but is not working...

`'binary' => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64',`

and with this line too

`'binary' => base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'),`

but is not working...

have ubuntu

php 7.0

laravel 5.5

Thanks

Comment: Is file permission accessible???

Comment: i don't understand what mean that? ... i try to say why permission can be the problem here @A.ANoman ?

Thank you

Comment: If your file path is correct and permission is ok then It works fine I can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to install snappy dependancy using `composer require knplabs/knp-snappy` (please see this [repository](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy#wkhtmltopdf-binary-as-composer-dependencies))

then the binaries will be at `/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64/bin and /vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin`

Move the binaries to a path that is not in a synced folder, for example:

`cp vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 /usr/local/bin/
cp vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/local/bin/`

and make it executable:

`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`

This will prevent the error 126.

Please see and go through the documentation [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

If you followed the vagrant steps, the line should look like

'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64',

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to download wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage with composer you add to composer.json:

   $ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386 0.12.x
   $ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-i386 0.12.x

or this if you are in 64 bit based system:

```
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 0.12.x
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 0.12.x
```

You should be able to use it from cmd/terminal now.
You can use it in PHP like this:

```
<?php

use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

$myProjectDirectory = '/path/to/my/project';

$snappy = new Pdf($myProjectDirectory . '/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386');

// or

$snappy = new Pdf($myProjectDirectory . '/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64');
```

If you're a `vagrant` user, you should move binaries to unsynced folder by using `mv` command. Then make exdcutable by using `chmod +x` command.
You can add requirement like this:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy
```

Then update composer by using this command

```
php composer.phar update
```

You can find basic usage [here...](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy#usage)

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution

$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 0.12.x
$ composer require h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 0.12.x

my error was put this comand in the project folder, but is in the root...

thanks